# WinAPI - How to make a owner draw button behave like a push button?

Tags: winapi

I haven't found a way to remove the border of windows buttons, so I decided to create an ownerdrawn button which is working fine but I want to make it look like a pushbutton when you click it, how do I go about this? Is it possible?

Edit: The GIF below explains everything, in short I want to make the ownerdraw (orange button) have the same animation as the static button in the middle, that is, to move when you press it

[image]

Comment: Fundamentally, if you do owner (or custom) drawing, you can make it look however you want. Push buttons have borders, which you say you want to remove. Which aspects of the push button do you wish to keep?

Comment: What does it mean to remove the border of windows buttons？ Or do you just want to change the background of the button?

Comment: @JonathanPotter just the animation when you click it

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I've included an image

Comment: The image you've posted looks like it uses the old, pre-Visual Styles button with a 3D effect. When those buttons get pressed, the contents are rendered at an offset towards the bottom right, to create the illusion of depths. With Visual Styles, push buttons use a flat appearance. Pushing those buttons doesn't offset the contents; the only animations are fade-in and fade-out animations, that change color over time, not the location or scale. The image doesn't help to convey the animation effect you are going for.

Comment: @IInspectable check my question again, I think I made it more clear

Comment: @JonathanPotter I included a gif to illustrate my point better

Comment: When you click the middle button, the border colors are inverted. If you have a flat (or no) border, then its hard to see how this could work. You'll need to come up with another way to indicate the button is being pushed. You're drawing it, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Have you considered setting another image background to show the button action? Such as this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz8mX.gif). You can design a dark image with the same color to simulate clicking.

Comment: You are using the old, unthemed controls. Do you want to continue to use those, or are you looking to implement a UI that follows the new(-er) themed controls. If it's the latter, see [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview).

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT thank you! That's exactly what I had in mind

Comment: @Trey Glad to help! Because in one of my previous projects, I encountered a similar image button problem. And in the end I used two images to solve this problem.

Comment: @Trey If you think this method is right for you, I will post an answer to end this question.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT yes, please

Comment: @Trey I've posted an answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two images with different color depths to simulate the visual effect of clicking.

Here is some code for your reference:

```
// Test_Button.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "Test_Button.h"
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Comctl32.lib")

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON 101

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerDrawButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
HWND hWndStatic;
HBITMAP hBmp1;
HBITMAP hBmp;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTBUTTON, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);


    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTBUTTON));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TESTBUTTON));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TESTBUTTON);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
            IMAGE_BITMAP,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
        hBmp1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2),
            IMAGE_BITMAP,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
        hWndStatic = CreateWindowEx(0, L"button", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 500, 400, 46, 29, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON, hInst, NULL);
        SetWindowSubclass(hWndStatic, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON, 0);     
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {          
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerDrawButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    BITMAP          bitmap01;
    HDC             hdcMem01;
    HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap01;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        RECT rc;
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        hdcMem01 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap01 = SelectObject(hdcMem01, hBmp1);

        GetObject(hBmp1, sizeof(bitmap01), &bitmap01);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap01.bmWidth, bitmap01.bmHeight, hdcMem01, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem01, oldBitmap01);  
        DeleteDC(hdcMem01);
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        RECT rc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        hdcMem01 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap01 = SelectObject(hdcMem01, hBmp);

        GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bitmap01), &bitmap01);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap01.bmWidth, bitmap01.bmHeight, hdcMem01, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem01, oldBitmap01);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem01);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);   
    }
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        hdcMem01 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap01 = SelectObject(hdcMem01, hBmp);

        GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bitmap01), &bitmap01);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap01.bmWidth, bitmap01.bmHeight, hdcMem01, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem01, oldBitmap01);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem01);
    }
    break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, 1);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Debug:

[image]

Comment: I just have one more question, do you HAVE to use windowsubclassing for this or could you have done it in the main window procedure by trapping WM_DRAWITEM?

Comment: @Trey Use `SetWindowSubclass`. I need to handle press and release of the mouse in subclass callbacks.